# mismatch detected for CRT library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, linker

I'm facing the following error message:

```
libcpmt.lib(stdhndlr.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in libcpmtd.lib(xlock.obj)
libcpmt.lib(stdhndlr.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MTd_StaticDebug' in mtu.obj
```

I have been searching over the internet but found nothing about **CRT** libraries being mismatched.

I have tried to define following preprocessor definition: `_ALLOW_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL_MISMATCH` however it did not resolved my issue.

I'm trying to compile a `Debug` configuration (`Release` is compiling fine).

Project runtime library is being set to:
`Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)`

How can I link a debug version of `libcpmt.lib`?

Comment: You *are* linking to the debug lib `libcpmtd.lib`, but seems to also link to the release version. Probably one of the included libraries are **not** a debug version.

Comment: The library you link was built with Release configuration settings.  But you built your program with Debug settings.  Mixing is not possible, that causes very nasty memory corruption problems because the size of the template class objects is not the same.  You'll have to rebuild the library with Debug configuration settings.  Adding the library project to your solution so everything is always built with consistent settings is by far the best way to keep out of trouble.

Comment: This thing is, I have never used/defined a dependency of `libcpmt.lib` in my project.

Comment: I also got this error, and I used the workaround of adding `libcpmt` to `Ignore Specific Default Libraries`